# Programmically create a content type with publishing options

Tags: 8, entities

I've been able to successfully create a content type on the install of my module by following [Creating a custom content type in Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/entity-api/creating-a-custom-content-type-in-drupal-8) in the drupal.org documentation, but I can't find a way to add the publishing options.

> [image: screenshot]

How should I add the publishing options when creating a content type?

Comment: I was going to write an answer, but I don't have all the information. The form to edit a content type (returned from [NodeTypeForm::form()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21src%21NodeTypeForm.php/function/NodeTypeForm%3A%3Aform/8.4.x)) seems to add those options unconditionally. I see that the Forum module is overriding the _promote_ property for the forum content type, but I cannot say in which way that influences showing that options.

Answer (score 3):

You have to add a base field override to change the default value of `status`, `promote` and `sticky` for newly created nodes. For the first and second option the default value is predefined as TRUE and for the third option as FALSE in the base field definition of the entity type. See this example for `promote`:

*Drupal\node\Entity\Node::baseFieldDefinitions*

```
$fields['promote'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('boolean')
  ->setLabel(t('Promoted to front page'))
  ->setRevisionable(TRUE)
  ->setTranslatable(TRUE)
  ->setDefaultValue(TRUE)
  ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
    'type' => 'boolean_checkbox',
    'settings' => [
      'display_label' => TRUE,
    ],
    'weight' => 15,
  ])
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE);
```

The base field override needs only to be present if you want to change this preset for a specific content type.

Example for the `status` field:

**foobar/config/install/core.base_field_override.node.car_brand.status.yml**

```
# core.base_field_override.node.car_brand.status.yml
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
  config:
    - node.type.car_brand
id: node.car_brand.status
field_name: status
entity_type: node
bundle: car_brand
label: 'Publishing status'
description: 'A boolean indicating the published state.'
required: false
translatable: true
default_value:
  -
    value: 0
default_value_callback: ''
settings:
  on_label: 'On'
  off_label: 'Off'
field_type: boolean
```

You can override the fields `promote` and `sticky` the same way.

---

The same task in PHP:

```
$fields = \Drupal::service('entity_field.manager')->getFieldDefinitions('node', 'car_brand');
$fields['status']->getConfig('car_brand')
  ->setDefaultValue(FALSE)
  ->save();
```

The method [BaseFieldDefinition::getConfig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21BaseFieldDefinition.php/function/BaseFieldDefinition%3A%3AgetConfig/8.3.x) loads an existing base field override or creates one if none exists from the base field definition in the entity type.

Using the PHP code in an install hook is IMHO the better solution, because you only need to change the default value and don't need to repeat all other values.

Comment: [NodeTypeForm::form()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21src%21NodeTypeForm.php/function/NodeTypeForm%3A%3Aform/8.4.x) doesn't check the fields exist, when it adds the _Publishing options_ part of the settings. Are you able to explain why it is necessary to add the fields to the node? Also, the Forum module just adds the _Promote_ field.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, this is an additional yaml file for the linked doc https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/entity-api/creating-a-custom-content-type-in-drupal-8. When you use this yaml file the first checkbox in the screenshot will be unchecked. Doing this for `promote` or `sticky` is for the second or third checkbox.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't say why it is necessary, considering the code used to show those field settings.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, I don't understand. The question is about creating a content type on the install of a module by following the linked documentation, which describes how to do this by using yaml files. My answer is to override the default values by adding more yaml files. And this will show up in the Default Options where the red circle is.

Comment: I understand the question and the answer. I was going to give a similar answer, but then I noticed I am not able to explain *why* that file is necessary, since the form builder for the node type forms is always showing those settings.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, I've looked in the code, I think I found what you are looking for. The node type forms gets the default values from the entity type base fields with a trick `// Create a node to get the current values for workflow settings fields.
    $node = $this->entityManager->getStorage('node')->create(['type' => $type->id()]);` A new node instance has the default values including the overrides specific to the bundle.

Comment: That is used to get its default values, not to choose which setting value to show. The code that shows the settings form field is the following: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9QoM.png. The #options array always contains 4 values.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, yes, and the first three items of the array `$workflow_options` are built with the newly created content entity `$node` and are not values of the config entity `$type`, which you would expect normally from a config entity form.

Comment: Those are the default values for the publishing options, not which checkboxes the form will show for the publishing options. The OP says _but I can't find a way to add the publishing options_, not _but I can't find a way to set the default values for the publishing options_.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, the OP wants to add the publishing options to the set of the  yaml files. In the linked documentation he was able to find all other settings, but not these three publishing options. This is now clear why they are missing in the yaml file of the content type, because they are stored in base field overrides.

Comment: Thanks for the info @4k4! Aww, it's a little harsh that I can't just add another line of code in my .yml file... :( I'll try it out and get back to you. Thanks again.